# Sonata admin, use text filter for date filter

Tags: filter, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle and I have a question about filters.

When I have a text field in my entity, in my filter I can see 3 types of filters :

- contains
- not contains
- is equal

When I have a date field in my entity, i can see these filters :

- =
- >=
- <
- ...

How can I use text filters instead of date filters (or math filters) when I have a date field ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to match date type of object using **`LIKE => contains/NOT LIKE => not contains (text filters)`** why you want these text filters for date type both types are totally different